# Google adsense bombing

Tags: google-adsense

I made a website few months ago and put google adsense on it, but someone kept clicking on ads with bad intentions, e.g. google bombing I guess but as result they disabled my google adsense account, now I wonder how did this all happened and what steps should I take in future to stop such kind of attacks.

Is there any tricks or tips to save your website from bombing of invalid clicks ?

what ways do normally hacker use to bomb adsense on a website ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to know the software they're using.

By the way..

How can you say that "someone kept clicking on ads with bad intentions"?

Is that the reason your Adsense account was banned?

Are you aware that your account is gone and it *probably* will never come back?

THAT SAID

There's **a good way to discover if you're website is victim of click bombing**.
You could replace the Adsense Ads with a dummy skyscraper linked to a very simple script that logs the IP (and maybe time or other useful data like User Agents).
You should easily spot a malicious behaviour.

Be also aware that you can **report invalid clicks to Google** itself using this form:
https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/request.py?&contact_type=invalid_clicks_contact

As prevention, you can **show ads only to people coming from search engines**. Some example here:

- http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-display-adsense-to-search-engines-visitors-only
- wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ozh-who-sees-ads/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because there were few people jealous of my website, well you can say my ex-mate, but I never realized that and I was totally new to adsense couldn't understand what happened was just getting happy with new people coming on my website and they were clicking which excited me for a while tho

Comment: I can't upvote u as my reputation isn't above 15, sorry and also, most user coming to my website were referrals so putting ads to organic search user wasn't a good strategy at that time you know. but thanks for advise :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance that your close friend has good intentions and clicks on website ads to generate profit for you. (He may not be informed that you will lose your AdSense account.)

Comment: I would like to know what software did they use, so that I could find a solution for that problem ;)